# Unable to instantiate traversable resolver class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I am working on fixing the junit for some old code. I am getting below exception for one of the test.

```
Unable to instantiate traversable resolver class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolve
```

I checked in my class path there is no  `org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolve`class found, Rather I found the same class in org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolve  in this path.

I am using `hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final` in my pom.xml

Above error i am getting in test class when I instantiate the my `CustomRequestValidatorClass` 
which has following code

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Set;

public CustomRequestValidatorClass
{
   private Validator validator;


    public CustomRequestValidatorClass() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }
}
```

I am getting above error when code reaches

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();  line.
```

May i know Why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have conflicting versions of Hibernate Validator in your classpath.

Can you check with `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: I don't see any version conflict